# Ubuntu 18.04 opens two terminals. How to fix?

Tags: command-line

I am using ubuntu 18.04 version. It was working fine but from last two days when I am opening the terminal through side bar by right click the mouse it opens up two terminal in place of one.
How to fix it.

[image: open Two Terminals with a single click]